# Can unused private variables be GCed before their holding instance?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Consider the following class:

```
public class MemoryTest
{
  private long[] longArr; // Eclipse marks this unused

  public MemoryTest(int arrSize) {
    longArr = new long[arrSize*10];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numObjs = 10000;
    MemoryTest[] mts = new MemoryTest[numObjs];

    for(int i = 0; i < numObjs; i++) {
      // build a large number of objects which hold expensive, unused references
      mts[i] = new MemoryTest(i);
      //System.gc(); interestingly, uncommenting this line causes OOM earlier
      System.out.println("Built "+i+": "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024+"KB");
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(mts)); // so elements cannot be GCed earlier
  }
}
```

This fails like so:

```
... truncated output ...
Built 5236: 62070KB
Built 5237: 61661KB
Built 5238: 61252KB
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at MemoryTest.<init>(MemoryTest.java:6)
    at MemoryTest.main(MemoryTest.java:15)
```

Obviously this is a contrived example, but I was wondering if the GC/JIT compiler could ever tidy up this object given that `longArr` isn't used anywhere.  As of Java 7 it seems to not tidy this up now, but if the compiler gets smarter or we change the example in some way could this ever happen, or is it contractually forbidden by the JVM?

Comment: I'm guessing the effort required to do the call hierarchy and data flow analysis to determine that the string does not ever escape is just not worth the effort, especially since you go through the bother of making sure the `mts` list can't be optimised away completely. (For your desired behaviour to be possible, the GC would have to consider not just whether objects are reachable, but whether any methods that may be called on any object might *at any point in the future* attempt to reach the objects being considered for GC, across the whole program, and considering reflection.)

Comment: Yet Java/Eclipse is smart enough at static compile time to know `longString` is unused, and issue a warning.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't need to consider any code you haven't told it about, or reflection, and it's up to you to actually delete the field. The JVM can't make that sort of guess. Imagine that the JVM actually optimizes away the field losing data in it, and afterwards a JAR is loaded that wants to access the data after all? (The JVM can do deoptimisation in some cases, I believe when inlining nonfinal methods or something like that.) This is what I meant at "any point in the future". There's no way to reverse the decision when you optimise away data, instead of just code.

Comment: To give a more specific example, imagine I'm making an application structured as a plugin framework that dynamically loads plugins from JARs from a directory. During initialisation, the plugins register, say, menu commands in my framework. Obviously I'm never compiling the framework and the plugins in one go. Now I have a situation where the compiler statically never sees anything being added to the list of menu actions. So you're proposing that it should be okay for the JVM to just nuke that list from memory and `null` all references to it, arbitrarily and nondeterministically.

Comment: I'm not "proposing that it should be okay for the JVM to just nuke [private fields]" - I'm in fact glad to hear that this does not happen.  The purpose of the question was to ask *if* this were possible, not argue that it should.

Comment: In that case, while I doubt it's expressly forbidden for the GC to kill unused but reachable data, the GC behaviour is likely specified in terms of reachability alone, and as you can see killing unused-but-reachable data is a pretty bad idea upon closer inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your code does not (seem to) access `longArr` anywhere at compile time, it could still be accessed at any time by reflection, and this is something that the GC/JIT compiler cannot guess.

The only unused variables that could be removed are the local ones (whose reference can be cleared as soon as they are assigned). In fact, the Eclipse compiler even allows to remove them at compile time (see Preferences > Java > Compiler > Preserve unused local variables).

Comment: Is it the case that reflection can be contractually expected to access variables like this?  It seems perfectly possible (especially once we start using WeakReferences) to reflectively inspect an object that has already been GCed.

Comment: When you do reflection you need to start from some reference so I don't think it would be possible to inspect an object that is being GCed, except if your reflection code is called from some `finalize()` method (but you do not need reflection for that, you can break a lot of things with simple code in a `finalize` method)

Comment: @dimo414 Can you provide an actual example of inspecting an object that's been GCed? You either do reflection calls on the WeakReference, in which case the referred object being gone is an expected outcome whether you're using reflections or not. And if you do the reflection calls on the referred object you need to have a strong reference to it anyway. And yes, I think reflection can be contractually expected to access plain old private fields regardless or whether not nonreflective code accesses them. Why wouldn't it? Just because it throws a wrench into the viability of your desired feature?

Comment: That's true, didn't think through the weak reference case enough in my head.  It's not a "desired feature", I'm just trying to understand when I can trust the GC will not collect something.  It sounds like unused fields will not be GCed, which is perfectly fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

**longArr** is not used anywhere; but you are creating objects of your class **MemoryTest**. This means attribute **longArr** is getting initialized for each object.

So if reference to an object of your class is not null; then don't think there is any way to GC this attribute. **longArr** will always be tied through objects; so it can get cleaned up only when object gets GCed.

Comment: `longString` gets initialized to a string of length `strSeed*seed.length()`, not `null`.  That's why it OOMs.  The main method completes perfectly successfully if you comment out `longString = sb.toString();` leaving `longString` `null`.